# Stripe.js API: Is there a way to have user save card information and use it for transfer later?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments, fetch, payment

For creating charges, a user can save the card information by creating a customer object and be charged at a later date simply by providing a customer ID from the customer object created, so there is no need to provide the card information again, retrieve the token, and use it for creating charges API call. Just need the customer ID from the customer object stored in the application's server.

But for transferring funds to a user's debit card (https://stripe.com/docs/sending-transfers), the user would always have to provide the card information to retrieve the token via API call, and then use the token to make the transfer API call.

So for transferring funds API call, is there something like the customer ID where it replaces the need for a token, which is only retrieved when the card information is provided?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The documentation mentions that this method of paying out third parties has been deprecated. Stripe's API will disable support for recipients entirely at some point in the future. You should use [managed accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/managed-accounts) rather than recipients.

The documentation for creating bank transfers with managed accounts can be found [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/bank-transfers).

You definitely don't need to collect the information every time. You would collect the information once, and use the token to attach it as an external account to the managed account. Then you'd be able to create bank transfers to the external account, either [manually](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_transfer) using the API, or by telling Stripe to create transfers automatically based on the schedule of your choice.

Comment: in managed accounts, which API calls should I make to answer my question? Also, as for the token, doesn't it expire/invalid after one usage? That's why you create a Customer object.